# Drupal 7 doesn't upload images styles

Tags: php, .htaccess, azure, drupal, azure-web-app-service

I have a drupal 7 hosted on windows azure as web app.

When I upload an image into a content, my original image is stored in the files folder but its corresponding image styles are not stored (example in the thumbnail folder).

I tried this:

- Permissions 777/775
- Comment the following lines in the htaccess located in the files folder:

```bash
#Options None
#Options + FollowSymLinks
```

I have the impression that it is Azure which blocks the writing of the files because the htaccess can be changed only in its own editor and not in my ftp.

Comment: Why are you using drupal as webapp in azure ? 
What is your file configuration settings ?

Comment: My client wanted to host his site on azure.
What file are you talking about? Drupal? Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Since you deployed your app to Azure Web Apps, Azure would use IIS to host your app, and this is running on Windows Server machines. So `htaceess` and `permissions 777/775` don't work on Azure. Without any error message and how you deploy your Drupal app, it's hard to figure out what's wrong there.

However, I can successfully deploy Drupal 7 with template `Acquia Drupal 7 on MySQL` from Azure marketplace. I also tested to upload an image into a content and both of original and thumbnail image are stored properly. Maybe you can have a try.

- Choose template `Acquia Drupal 7 on MySQL` to create an Azure Web
  App.

[image]

- Upload image was worked fine.

[image]

Comment: Hello sorry for my delay. I tried with the same method as you but my image style (thumbnail) does not create  .. I really don't understand ..